# Teste de Desempenho de Upload e Inserção

Tags: desempenho, testes, testes-funcionais, jmeter

Sou novo no cenário de teste de desempenho.
Tenho que fazer um testes de desempenho em um sistema web (usa *Spring* e *Angular*) em que ele faz o upload de um arquivo com diversos cadastros em cada linha. Tenho que usar o *JMeter* para fazer este teste.

O que está acontecendo é o seguinte. O teste de upload do arquivo está funcionando perfeitamente, entretanto o mesmo não está inserindo no banco de dados as informações que estão no arquivo.

Tentei criar na mão todos os caminhos de *GET* e *POST* que o mesmo faz desde o login até chegar a importação, e também utilizei o plugin (ou extensão) da *BlazeMetter* para ele gravar o que eu fiz e assim conseguir exportar para o *JMeter*.

No *JMeter*, apesar de receber o código 200 para todas as requisições, não insere nada no banco de dados.

É possível testar pelo *JMeter* a inserção no banco de dados dos dados que vem do arquivo? Ou teria que criar 2 testes, um com o upload e outro só com os *inserts*? Tem como automatizar isso?

Espero que me ajudem e qualquer dúvida estou à disposição.